# What is -Xdiags:verbose with javac used for?

Tags: java, javac

If I want to compile a java file, I use javac command.
If I want to compile a java file with verbose output, I use javac -verbose.

Then what is the use of javac -Xdiags:verbose? Or what is the correct way to use it?
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/specs/man/javac.html suggests following usage of -Xdiags:verbose:

> -Xdiags:[compact, verbose]
> Selects a diagnostic mode.

Comment: Does this help? [The Hitchhiker's Guide to javac](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/compiler/doc/hhgtjavac/diagnostics.html)

Comment: So basically -Xdiags:verbose does nothing useful?